# Play-Framework 2.4: Unable to map Spring-Data-Mongodb repository with google guice depedency injection

Tags: java, spring, playframework, guice, spring-data-mongodb

`I am using`Play-Framework 2.4`, Spring-Data-MongoDb` and `Google Guice Dependency Injection` provide by **play-framework** for manage dependencies in application. But when i used `Spring-Data` with `Play` and `Dependency Injection`, my `Spring-Data` repositories are not mapped with their internal implementation that provide by spring. My code is following:

```
@Named @Singleton
public interface UserRepo extends GenericRepository<User, String>, UserRepoCustom{

}

@Named @Singleton
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Inject
private UserRepo userRepo;

public void saveNewUser(User user) {
    userRepo.save(user);
}
..........................
```

In above case following exception is throw by playframework:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for repository.UserRepo was bound.
  while locating repository.UserRepo
for field at    service.impl.UserServiceImpl.userRepo(UserServiceImpl.java:24)
  while locating service.UserService
for field at controllers.Application.userService(Application.java:15)
  while locating controllers.Application
for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:32)
 while locating router.Routes
 while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
 while locating play.api.routing.Router

1 error
```

When i am using Spring annotations instead of `javax`, i got the NullPointerException as below:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends GenericRepository<User, String>, UserRepoCustom{

}

@Named @Singleton
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

public void saveNewUser(User user) {
    userRepo.save(user);
}
.........................
```

Following is my Exception thrpow by play-Framework:

```
[NullPointerException: null]

private UserRepo userRepo;

public void saveNewUser(User user) {
    userRepo.save(user); //[NullPointerException: null]
}
.................................
```

How could i resolve this issue?

Comment: We are using Spring-Data with Play app too but letting Spring handle its own dependency injection mechanism. To access Spring handled repository or services from Play's side, we have an abstraction class. Other way, we could not handle Spring dependency with guice

Comment: @SerhatCan the problem is that, now i was disable `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` from my `build.sbt` and use only spring depedency injection instead of `Guice`. But now the problem is that, my spring `@Autowire` annotation inject `null` in controller layer for service instance like: `@Autowired(required=true)private UserService userService;`

Comment: Then, you may try to give proper folder route to Spring configuration so that your controllers also handled by Spring. As you know, this happends your controllers are not Spring beans meaning that Spring does not about them. Try to let them by giving proper folder route in Spring config.

Comment: @SerhatCan this is my new problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406005/play-framework-2-4-use-sping-depedency-injection-with-play-framework-instead-of. Please check what the problem with that ?

Comment: I've checked your question and gave an answer based on my previous findings.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara - Were you able to get around the problem that you described in your question? I am in the same boat now (using play 2.4.4 with spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Hello @Mubin the problem is to inject repository implementation that provide by spring are not injected.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara, ya I understand the problem and I am struggling with the same problem now. Were you able to find a solution? If so, can you  please share that with me?

Comment: Please have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43440349/3563224

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Guice for your injection, you need you to create a module definition to bind the interfaces to their implementations. I don't see that in your snippets, have you done that?

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Providing-custom-bindings

Comment: Hello @easel the problem is that, that repository implementation define by spring not by user. So, that's why i am not defining its implementation.